# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs - can't build a project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I'm migrating my project from eclipse to Android Studio and ran into an error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I've searched through this problem and seen that I need to use

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

in the manifest tag
and

```
tools:node="replace"
tools:replace="icon"
```

in the application tag. but that didn't help me. I presume that there is something to do with Gradle/Manifest working failure, but not sure where

Here's manifest (it's the only Manifest in App module)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vladdrummer.headsup"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.01" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:replace="icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

and here's Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vladdrummer.headsup"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.01"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':ldialogs')
}
```

just in case : here's the library's (module) manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="uk.me.lewisdeane.ldialogs">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/lib_name"

        android:supportsRtl="true">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here's the module's Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: there must be another manifest file in your project inside other libraries. isn't it?

Comment: yes, it's in library module. It had problems but then it was fixed , so now error is on App module

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay I added library's manifest and gradle too

Comment: try it after removing the application tag from the library manifest.

Comment: Paste these line in manifest file :- xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:replace="android:icon" and then rebuild your project

Comment: @Bhavnik don't you see them in manifest already?

Comment: read my line properly, you will find it's difference

Comment: You haven't added `tools:replace="android:theme"`. Try adding and rebuild your project

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay you mean, instead of tools:replace="android:icon" in application tag? It didn't help